# Como saber a alteração que um plugin fez no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Boa tarde,

Tinha um problema com um menu no meu Wordpress, e resolvi utilizando um plugin. Gostaria de saber como o plugin resolveu o meu problema em questões de código, existe alguma forma de ver as alterações que o plugin realizou?

Answer (score 0):

A resposta está no seu plugin. Se ele faz: "Inserir cor de fundo aos itens do menu" e você quer saber como ele põe essa cor, você tem que entender sobre:

- `add_action( 'wp_head'...`,
- `add_filter('...`,
- `add_action('customize_register...`,
- `add_action('admin_head...`.

Estes plugins, que você ta falando, normalmente só acessam o core do wordpress e fazem suas alterações,
   de acordo com o thema ou não.